# Allow VPN Client access local server with private IP (iptables)?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I would like to allow VPN clients to access a local server using OpenVPN on a raspPi

I have a local DNS server (piHole) that is accepting the requests and I can see the client IP address (not the OpenVPN Server ip) when they are doing DNS lookups (even local A records are showing in the query log correctly)

if I add this `-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` to my iptables I can access the server, but it always shows the OpenVPN server IP address

The local LAN IP range is 172.26.19.0/27 and the OpenVPN is passing client IP's as 172.26.18.0/27

I want to be able to determine what IP is accessing the local server, not just see the OpenVPN server accessing on the clients behalf... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So anyone looking for an answer:

**Disable NAT on the VPN**

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

*NOTE TO SELF*
Install iptables-persistent if iptables-save does not work

**Add a static route on your router**

Destination network: 192.16.19.0/27 (Change to your network)

Gateway: 192.16.19.2 (change to your VPN gateway)